# A set that is transitive but not well-ordered by $\in$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I am trying to find a transitive set which is not well-ordered by $\in$. This question raises when I read Jech's *Set Theory*, in which an ordinal number is defined as a transitive and $\in$-well-ordered set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$V_\omega$ is a very easy example; more generally, $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha\ge 2$. In particular, $\{0,1,2,\{1\}\}$ is a small example.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice small example! Though I have no idea what $V_\omega$ is...

Comment: @xuhdev: You’re welcome! $V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th level of the [von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) of sets.

Comment: It appears that the examples fail just because they are not totally ordered. Indeed the axiom of regularity would seem to imply that $\in$ on any transitive class gives a well founded relation. If that is so, then why would one speak of $\in$-well-ordered instead of $\in$-totally-ordered (which appears to me a simpler notion)? (Excuse my abuse of a comment for asking a new question...)

Comment: @Marc: In the case of ordinals because the fact that they are well-ordered by $\in$ is just about their most important characteristic. I suspect that this exercise is intended primarily to emphasize that not all transitive sets are ordinals, so it’s natural to ask for a transitive set that isn’t well-ordered by $\in$, even though that’s equivalent to asking for one that’s not linearly ordered.